# Database sql count wins and loses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
home  | away  | home_round_1 | away_round_1 | home_round_2 | away_round_2
team1   team2       20              10             5             -2
team3   team1        1               2             -11            4
team2   team3       20              -1             -1            10
```

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate wins, loses, evens and average game result group by teams. Game result sit counted as home round 1 + round 2 or away round 1 + round 2 and winner is team that has less points in the end. I have made counter that count certain teams average in mysql with cases but is it possible to count all this inside mysql, that it will count values by team.
So far I have manage to count team avrage with this:

```
SELECT
      AVG(
          CASE
              WHEN home = "team1" THEN home_round_1 + home_round_2
              WHEN away = "team1" THEN away_round_1 + away_round_2
              ELSE NULL
         END
        ) AS 'Avrage_points'
    FROM
      `Game_results`
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: This data is denormalised. You'll find this task far easier if you have a separate table for the individual games (with foreign keys back to the main home/away pairing), instead of spreading it across multiple columns.

Comment: @ADyson can you open more what are you saying? I didn't really get it.

Comment: If you don't know what i mean I suggest you study the concepts of database normalisation and entity-relationship design and then you will understand how to correctly create a relational database structure.

Comment: Ok I learned about normalization and I still don't get you point.  You say: "separate table for the individual games". I think now I understand what you think. You think that in the one row is two (or more) games, right? In my example, every row is individual game. In every game there is two rounds and between rounds, the game is reset, so that explains the different scores. The game result is counted as this = home:   home_round_1 + home_round_2 and away: away_round_1 + away_round_2. So, in the end my data is normalized.